# Kendo theme doesn't change for charts

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to change my kendo ui theme from default. The problem is it changes but only for controls: grid etc. but charts stay exactly the same.

I'm adding this styles in the bundle.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendoUi").Include(
    "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.common.min.css",
    "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.mobile.all.min.css",
    "~/Content/kendo/2016.1.112/kendo.metro.min.css"
));
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was struggeling with the same thing today. For some reason, the Theme of a chart must be set via widget configuration.

From the [Documentation of the Kendo Client Library](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/appearance):

> The Kendo UI Chart widgets come with a set of predefined themes. Use
>   the theme option to select a theme, as demonstrated in the example
>   below. The theme name is case insensitive.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    theme: "blueOpal",
    //...
});
```

There is no documentation for the Server-Wrappers. However, it will work this way:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart().Theme("blueOpal"))
```

The reason for this, seems to be [explained here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/appearance-styling):

> Kendo UI Gauges, Charts, Barcodes, Diagrams, and Maps use a mix of
>   browser technologies to attain the required precision and
>   responsiveness. **Visualization is rendered as vector graphics with
>   computed layout**. In contrast, interactive features are built using
>   traditional HTML elements. **As a result, the appearance settings of
>   these widgets are split between declarative options and traditional
>   CSS**.

If you want to do it globaly, you need to [override kendo](http://blog.falafel.com/custom-skin-kendo-ui-dataviz-components/):

```
var themable = ["Chart", "TreeMap", "Diagram", "StockChart", "Sparkline", "RadialGauge", "LinearGauge"];

if (kendo.dataviz) {
  for (var i = 0; i < themable.length; i++) {
    var widget = kendo.dataviz.ui[themable[i]];

    if (widget) {
      widget.fn.options.theme = "blueOpal";
    }
  }
}
```